# Populate select only if option tag doesn't exist

Tags: jquery

I want to populate the select `#current_location` only if it hasn't been done yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#current_location').on('change', function (){
                   /*
                    * Populate the select
                    * I want to populate the select only if it hasn't been done yet
                    */
                   $.getJSON('fetch.php', {action: 'homepage' , key: 'current_location' }, function(data){
                       var options = '';
                       for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                           options += '<option value="' + data[x] + '">' + data[x] + '</option>';
                       }
                       $('#current_location').html(options);
                   });


                $.getJSON('fetch.php', {action: 'homepage' , key: $('#current_location').val() }, function(data){
                    var options = '';
                    for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + data[x] + '">' + data[x] + '</option>';
                    }
                    $('#destination').html(options);
                });

            });
        });
```

Comment: @SougataBose post as an answer so that i can close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there is no `option`s present and add `option`s accordingly.

```
if($('#current_location').find('option').length < 1) {
    .... // add options
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check `option` length .

```
var length = $('#YourSelectList')
    .children('option')
    .length;
if (length > 0) {

} else {

}
```